# How many files in a directory is too many for ext4?

Tags: filesystems, performance, ext4

I wrote a Golang program to measure how long it takes to create 100 new files and read 100 existing files in a directory with 2k files vs a directory with 200k files:

```go
// Create 200k files in one directory vs 200k files in 100 separate directories
// See if speed of accessing files is affected
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/1f604/util"
)

func main() {
    // First, create 100 directories
    filepaths := []string{}
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        newfilepath := "/tmp/dir" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(i)) + "/"
        filepaths = append(filepaths, newfilepath)
        err := os.MkdirAll(newfilepath, os.ModePerm)
        util.Check_err(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Created 100 directories.")
    // Next, create 2k files in each directory
    fmt.Println("Now creating 2k x 10kb files in each small directory.")
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 2000; j++ {
            f, err := os.Create("/tmp/dir" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(i)) + "/" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(j)) + ".txt")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            if err := f.Truncate(1e4); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
    }

    // Next, create 200k files in one directory
    fmt.Println("Now creating 200k x 10kb files in one big directory.")
    for j := 0; j < 200000; j++ {
        f, err := os.Create("/tmp/bigdir/" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(j)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := f.Truncate(1e4); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    // Now time read and write times
    fmt.Println("Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a small directory.")
    start := time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
        f, err := os.Create("/tmp/dir1/test" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(j)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := f.Truncate(1e4); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))

    fmt.Println("Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a small directory.")
    start = time.Now()
    list := [][]byte{}
    for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
        num, err := util.Crypto_Randint(2000)
        util.Check_err(err)
        contents, err := os.ReadFile("/tmp/dir2/" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(num)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        list = append(list, contents)
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))

    fmt.Println("Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a big directory.")
    start = time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
        f, err := os.Create("/tmp/bigdir/test" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(j)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := f.Truncate(1e4); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))

    fmt.Println("Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a big directory.")
    start = time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
        num, err := util.Crypto_Randint(200000)
        util.Check_err(err)
        contents, err := os.ReadFile("/tmp/bigdir/" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(num)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        list = append(list, contents)
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))

    start = time.Now()
}
```

Here are my results on my Debian 12 (ext4) system:

```
Created 100 directories.
Now creating 2k x 10kb files in each small directory.
Now creating 200k x 10kb files in one big directory.
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 2.361316ms
Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 5.792292ms
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 2.922209ms
Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 3.835541ms
```

Reading 100 random files from the big directory was consistently faster than reading 100 random files from the small directory, but how is this possible?

Is my benchmarking code incorrect?

Thanks.

UPDATE: After applying @Paul_Pedant's suggestion to flush the page cache after creating the files I got totally different results!

here are my new results:

```
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 19.475348ms
Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 26.309475ms
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 75.570411ms
Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 152.495391ms
```

This shows that the surprising results that I saw earlier were just due to the effects of the page cache and that reading 100 random files from a 200K file directory is indeed much slower than reading 100 random files from a 2K file directory (152ms vs 26ms)

UPDATE: I realized that my original test wasn't fair, because I was accessing all 100 files from the same small directory, but in a realistic scenario I would be accessing them from random directories.

So I updated my benchmarking program to make it more realistic (note: this program assumes you have already created the directories and files. You need to flush page cache before running this program):

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "math/rand"

    "github.com/1f604/util"
)

func main() {
    // Now time read and write times
    fmt.Println("Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a small directory.")
    start := time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
        num1 := rand.Intn(100)
        num2 := rand.Intn(2000)
        f, err := os.Create("/tmp/dir" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(num1)) + "/test" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(num2)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := f.Truncate(1e5); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))

    fmt.Println("Now reading 1000 random 10kb files in a small directory.")
    start = time.Now()
    list := [][]byte{}
    for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
        num1 := rand.Intn(100)
        num2 := rand.Intn(2000)
        contents, err := os.ReadFile("/tmp/dir" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(num1)) + "/" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(num2)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        list = append(list, contents)
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))

    fmt.Println("Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a big directory.")
    start = time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
        f, err := os.Create("/tmp/bigdir/test" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(j)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := f.Truncate(1e5); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))

    fmt.Println("Now reading 1000 random 10kb files in a big directory.")
    start = time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
        num := rand.Intn(200000)
        contents, err := os.ReadFile("/tmp/bigdir/" + util.Int64_to_string(int64(num)) + ".txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        list = append(list, contents)
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", time.Now().Sub(start))
}
```

And here are my new results:

```
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 70.31699ms
Now reading 1000 random 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 758.609004ms
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 32.695134ms
Now reading 1000 random 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 574.266544ms
```

(These results are obtained after flushing the page cache)

Now it seems all the advantage of the small directory has disappeared. Instead, it seems the big directory is now faster.

I think this shows that if you repeatedly access the same directory then it will make subsequent file accesses faster? Another explanation is that since the files are so small (10kb) they're sitting in the same block on the physical device so accessing nearby files is faster. I don't know though.

Comment: You probably need to clear cache between each create and read test operation, to get meaningful figures.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Wow you're completely right! After I flushed the page cache I got totally the opposite results: now reading from big directory is much slower! 


Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 19.475348ms
Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 26.309475ms
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 75.570411ms
Now reading 100 random 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 152.495391ms

Comment: xfs ftw!  :) :) :)

Comment: I'm no longer sure what the question is, if it isn't "_How many files in a directory is too many for ext4?_". Either that's a factual question that could be resolved by looking up the specifications for ext4 or it's a question seeking an opinion based on unspecified criteria

Comment: @ChrisDavies The practical application is: suppose I want to store lots of files on disk, and I want to be able to access files quickly. I know the full path of each file. In this scenario, which is faster: storing them all in one big directory, or in lots of small directories? Intuitively one would think that if the number of files is large, then putting them into small directories would make access faster, but at what point does it make sense to do so?

Comment: @1f604 could you elaborate what you mean with "accessing them", specifically?

Comment: In that case, please could you clarify that in your question. From a practical basis it's generally easier to search through 2000 files than 200,000 files. Personally I would always recommend you split a (very) large set of files into multiple subdirectories even if the computers involved don't care. Never underestimate the ability to debug a problem!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm building a pastebin-like website so I'm storing large numbers of small files (max size 1MB) on disk that need fast random read. Write performance is not that important, but obviously the faster the better. I'm not going to be searching for files since I'm storing all the file paths in a large hash map in memory, and I will also store the file paths in a log file so I don't need to ever list all the files in a directory.

Comment: That frankly sounds like by far the fastest thing to do is *not* to use the file system to store all these snippets, but instead drop it into a single database file. But assuming you want the ease of using the file system: all in one directory should be faster than several directories, because the list of files in that one directory would definitely remain cached. And: ext4 has a directory index (based on BTree-alike data structures) so, lookups in a single directory should be relatively fast, faster than looking up different directories. However, as ron mentions very briefly:

Comment: for file systems with directories with very many entries, XFS might be the slightly better design, still.

Comment: Generally, your benchmarking seems to be a bit questionable: far too small number of files you actually access to make statistically significant statements!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I increased the read sample size to 1000 files 

Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 70.31699ms
Now reading 1000 random 10kb files in a small directory.
Time taken: 758.609004ms
Now creating 100 x 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 32.695134ms
Now reading 1000 random 10kb files in a big directory.
Time taken: 574.266544ms

Comment: 574 ms sounds *very* long; I think I can be faster using a shell script… Somethings seems wrong with your file access library.

Comment: nope, realistic, can reproduce a similar time with a shell script, using 2¹⁷ files and 1000 random from these. Do yourself the favor and benchmark a similar example using an  SQLite table (containing the payloads as BLOBs) instead of files, to get an idea about how much of your time is spend actually reading data and how much is just file lookup overhead :)

Answer (score -1):

> How many files in a directory is too many for ext4?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537471/what-is-the-max-files-per-directory-in-ext4

  - **It depends upon the MKFS parameters used during the filesystem creation. Different
    Linux flavors have different defaults, so it's really impossible to answer**
  - *The 48-bit block addressing suggests an absolute maximum number of files of 281,474,976,710,656.*
  - According to https://www.phoronix.com/news/EXT4-Linux-4.13-Work it's "roughly 10 million entries allowed in a single directory" however this can be extended with the large_dir feature, though there are limitations/issues with this (for example GRUB might not be able to use this partition to boot);  *anecdotal experience - ran into an issues once over about 32 million files in a single directory.*
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29894

  - A **directory** on ext4 can have at most 64000 sub directories
  - *If very long filenames are used, fewer entries will fit in the block, leading to 'directory index full' errors earlier than they would occur with shorter filenames.*
- https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/ext4.html

  - Information about mounted ext4 file systems can be found in /sys/fs/ext4